# CSS cursor is not inline in IE9

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9

when i use

> cursor: url(xxx.ico)

it works fine with chrome and FF.
but when i try to use IE9 when i hover the div - the cursor "jumps" 30px up.
why is that?

```
*( i tried to use 32X32 and 16X16 icons - and it's the same)
```

The CSS:

```
.main_div { 
cursor:url(/static/IMG/hand.ico),auto;
 }
```

thanks!

Comment: please add it to the question not in the comment